# Problem with installing Landscape 17.03

Tags: 16.04, landscape

I'm trying to install landscape-server on a fresh 16.04 installation, I'm doing this as is described on https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem

The installation itself seems to be going okay, no weird messages during configuration, all services seem to be running but for some reason when I go to the webinterface, it gives the error that "Landscape is unavailable. Service will resume shortly."

The logs only show this error, which seems related, but there's no information at all about how to fix it.

```
Jan 29 12:06:17 landscape.omitted appserver-1[18144]: Unhandled error in Deferred:
Jan 29 12:06:17 landscape.omitted appserver-1[18144]:
```

The hostname is omitted, but is in fact a valid fqdn. The empty error is not a copy/paste error, but is literally what's in the log. The landscape-appserver service is started, but only gives this error and nothing more.

If I had any other error message, I could check what's up; but this is it :/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into

> /var/log/landscape-server/

directory. It contains multiple log files that should help point to the problem.

Install is pretty simple, https://help.landscape.canonical.com/

```
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:landscape/17.03
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

I have just deployed that on 16.04 LTS and it works fine. I also run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

Hope this will help.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. I know it was a fairly simple installation; I've done it before without issues, which is why this was baffling to me.
In the end, the problem was with the fact that this server was not properly able to be reached from the internet, so a few adjustments on my loadbalancer fixed the issue.

Comment: No problem @Peter van Arkel Let me know if you will have anymore questions about Landscape